# limited scroll at a time

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose I have 5 divs with 100vh height each in a container.

```
<div class="mycontainer" >
    <div id="diview0" class="diview">0</div>
    <div id="diview1" class="diview">1</div>
    <div id="diview2" class="diview">2</div>
    <div id="diview3" class="diview">3</div>
    <div id="diview4" class="diview">4</div>
    <div id="diview5" class="diview">5</div>
    <div id="diview6" class="diview">6</div>
    <div id="diview7" class="diview">7</div>
    <div id="diview8" class="diview">8</div>
    <div id="diview9" class="diview">9</div>
</div>
```

I scroll in that container but what happens is if a scroll up then it scrolls the div too much.

What I want is that it scroll a limited portion only.

For ex: if I scroll down 100px then it's good but on more than that(like 200 or 300) it should only scroll down 110px
same goes for scrolling up if I scroll up 100px then it's good but on more than that(like 200 or 300) it should only scroll up 110px.

Requirement is only of JavaScript. No jQuery or any other external library can be used.
How can I do it?

Comment: I'm not fully understanding the issue. Do you mean a behaviour like the [CSS Scroll Snap API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type)?

Comment: It would be great if you could try something, or find an open source library that does the same that someone could explain. Otherwise, you're essentially asking for volunteers to write a whole component for you, which is not really what Stack Overflow was created for.

Comment: no i am not asking to create a whole component for me . just give me a basic logic or code of how to do it myself without using any external library, just a idea is enough

Answer (score 0):

This is a way of doing it:

```
let maxS = 110;
let t = 2;
function isScrollable(x) {
    let y = (Boolean(x))?"auto":"hidden";
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty("overflow", y);
}
function timeoutScroll() {
    let a = window.pageYOffset;
    const temp = setInterval(function() {
        if (window.pageYOffset >= a + maxS || window.pageYOffset <= a - maxS) {isScrollable(false)}},
                             100)
    setTimeout(function() {isScrollable(true); clearInterval(temp)}, t*1000);
}
```

And the *timeoutScroll* function would stop scrolling the page for *t* seconds for more than *maxS* pixels